# Load NFS-Kernel-Server modules via /etc/modules

Tags: kernel-modules, nfs

I have added the following to my `/etc/modules`:

```
nfs
nfsv4
```

and this is the result after a reboot:

```
nfsv4                 638976  0
nfs                   294912  1 nfsv4
lockd                  98304  1 nfs
fscache               368640  2 nfsv4,nfs
sunrpc                385024  4 nfsv4,lockd,nfs
```

But, if I install nfs-kernel-server, this is the result:

```
nfsv4                 638976  0
nfs                   294912  1 nfsv4
fscache               368640  2 nfsv4,nfs
nfsd                  368640  13
auth_rpcgss            94208  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
lockd                  98304  2 nfsd,nfs
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
sunrpc                385024  20 nfsd,nfsv4,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl,nfs
```

What am I not doing correctly to get the same kernel modules loaded that installing via "apt" gets me?

Update: this is the "pure" apt install output, the other output has my "/etc/modules" NFS line + APT mixed together.

```
nfsd                  368640  9
auth_rpcgss            94208  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
lockd                  98304  1 nfsd
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
sunrpc                385024  16 nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nfs` and `nfsv4` are the filesystem driver modules (the NFS client). `nfsd` is the NFS server module. The rest are their dependencies, such as `auth_rpcgss` which is needed to support Kerberos.

Comment: `nfsd` was what I was looking for, just hadn't submitted answer, thank you! Confusing to have just "nfs" not work, I kinda expected that to do "all" nfs, but i'm fairly new to loading modules this way.

Answer (score 0):

using just `nfsd` inside `/etc/modules` got me the correct modules.